# Borrar todo lo que sigue a un Carácter añadirle un string - PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario donde los usuarios deben poner su canal de YouTube, el problema es que a veces (No siempre, es decir, no debe dar error si no se encuentra), añaden en la url `?view_as=subscriber` y quiero que al obtener la URL, **se elimine todo lo que sigue al ?**, y luego, añadirle `?sub_confirmation=1`

He probado con esta respuesta pero no me sirve:

```
//$urls[0] = string(75) "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUF-TufbSRtKm5lUKWwqpFA?view_as=subscriber"

$sub = $urls[0].split("?");

echo $sub[0];

//Devuelve: "h"
```

Comment: Intenta con `echo $sub[0];`

Comment: Me devuelve "h". (string(1) "h").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

debes usar explode que es la funcion correcta en php:

```
//$urls[0] = string(75) "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUF-TufbSRtKm5lUKWwqpFA?view_as=subscriber"

$sub = explode("?", $urls[0]);;

echo $sub[0];
```